# Why should I refresh the page to render the data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, routes, react-router

I have a form and a table made for my app such that if I enter the data and submit it has to make a separate row for itself. It works but after submitting my form it gives me this route

[image]

only when I refresh the page it forms a row in the table

this the function that handles my form submission

```
 const handleSubmit = () => {
     

      setMessage("");
      setLoading(true);

      form.current.validateAll();

      if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {

        ProductService.addProduct(id, barcode, productName, price, quantity).then(
           (response, ) => {
               setMessage(response.data.message);
               setSuccessful(true);    
           },
           (error) => {
            const resMessage =
              (error.response &&
                error.response.data &&
                error.response.data.message) ||
              error.message ||
              error.toString();
  
            setMessage(resMessage);
            setSuccessful(false); 
           }
        );          
    }
  };
```

this function fetches data and updates state of my table

```
const InventoryTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = () => {
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/inventory/getProductData")
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((details) => setData(details));}

  


  useEffect(() => {
 fetchData();
  }, []);
```

The `ProductService.addProduct()` is a function from a service file that sends data to the API route and the code of that looks like this

```
    const addProduct = (id, barcode, productName, price, quantity) => {
    return axios.post(API_URL + "addProduct" , {
        username,
        id,
        barcode,
        productName,
        price,
        quantity,
    });
};
```

and the API route that is sent to has controller function called back that saves the product into MONGOdB

```
const addProduct = (req, res) => {

    User.findOne({
        username: req.body.username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err })
        }else{
          
            user.store.push({
      
                id: req.body.id, 
                barcode: req.body.barcode,
                productName : req.body.productName,
                price : req.body.price,
                quantity: req.body.quantity
            
            })
            user.save(function(err, newUser) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(500).send({ message: err });
                } else {
                    console.log(newUser);
                    res.status(200).send({ message: "Product updated successfully!!"})
                }
            })
        }
    })
  

    
};
```

and when I used `event.preventaDefault();` I had to refresh twice to make sure the data renders

Let me know if u guys need anything else to solve the issue

what should I do to take this problem?

and this is on react with react-router and backend with nodejs and database is mongodb

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the relevant code you've an issue with? Typically this means you're working with stale state and/or props.

Comment: Can you show the code of the component which renders and handles the form?

Comment: There is no way to pinpoint your problem without seeing your code.  In order for others to help you, you need to also post your code.  But it sounds like state is not being updated when the form is submitted, therefore components are not rerendered.

Comment: @DrewReese thank u for the quick response. I have edited my question with the code.

Comment: Is `ProductService.addProduct` the piece that is adding a row of data? What is giving you that route? What is the relevance of the route to the code snippet?

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited and added more snippets. Appreciating your quick response to help out. Thanks

Comment: Ok, and is `InventoryTable` the component that all this frontend code resides in? I suspect you need to either refetch data from the backend, or if the POST request returns the new data you can update the `data` state. I think the `preventDefault` is a relevant issue if you are using a form element's `onSubmit` handler. Perhaps a full UI component code example is in order so we can better track the flow of data.

Comment: @DrewReese No, the `InventoryTable` just maps through the data and renders rows of the table. Maybe it is because I have a separate `POST` request to send the username from localStorage and find the user data with that username and I fetch that data using the fetch() function. If that is the problem should I return the data in the `POST` request itself Or it doesn't make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `event.preventDefault();` starting of `handleSubmit` function.

[Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for your reference to get more idea.

Your updated `handleSubmit` function:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  setMessage("");
  setLoading(true);

  form.current.validateAll();

  if (checkBtn.current.context._errors.length === 0) {

    ProductService.addProduct(id, barcode, productName, price, quantity).then(
       (response, ) => {
           setMessage(response.data.message);
           setSuccessful(true);    
       },
       (error) => {
        const resMessage =
          (error.response &&
            error.response.data &&
            error.response.data.message) ||
          error.message ||
          error.toString();

        setMessage(resMessage);
        setSuccessful(false); 
       }
    );          
  }
};
```